# jQuery .click() and .change() conflict?

Tags: jquery, click, conflict, onchange

I have problem with .click() and .change() functions. I don't know why, but I put them into the html code separately they works, but when I put them together like below they stop working. What is the problem?
The .change() function populates the fields of form in specific table row. The .click() functions add a row to and remove a row from the table within the form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="produkt[]"]').change(function() {
        var id = $('select[name="produkt[]"] option:selected').val();
        var par = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        $.getJSON(
            '<?php echo $head['site_link'];?>index.php/faktura/pobierzProdukt/'+id,
            function(data){
                alert(par);
                $('#'+par+' input[name="pkwiu[]"]').val(data.product_pkwiu);
                $('#'+par+' input[name="netto[]"]').val(data.product_netto);
                $('#'+par+' input[name="vat[]"]').val(data.product_vat);
                $('#'+par+' input[name="brutto[]"]').val(data.product_brutto);
                $('#'+par+' input[name="jedn[]"]').val(data.product_jedn);
            },
            'json'
        );
    });

    $('#dodajWiersz').click(function() {
        var liczba = $('#produkty tr').length;
        var f1  = '<?php echo form_dropdown('produkt[]',$lista,'');?></td>';
        var f2  = '<?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'pkwiu[]','class'=>'short','readonly'=>'readonly'));?>';
        var f3  = '<?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'netto[]','class'=>'short','readonly'=>'readonly'));?>';
        var f4  = '<?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'vat[]','class'=>'mini','readonly'=>'readonly'));?>';
        var f5  = '<?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'brutto[]','class'=>'short','readonly'=>'readonly'));?>';
        var f6  = '<?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'jedn[]','class'=>'mini','readonly'=>'readonly'));?>';
        var f7  = '<?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'ilosc[]','class'=>'short'));?>';
        var f8  = '<?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'knetto[]','class'=>'short','readonly'=>'readonly'));?>';
        var f9  = '<?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'kvat[]','class'=>'short','readonly'=>'readonly'));?>';
        var f10 = '<?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'kbrutto[]','class'=>'short','readonly'=>'readonly'));?>';

        var row = '<tr id="wiersz-'+liczba+'"><td>'+liczba+'</td><td>'+f1+'</td><td>'+f2+'</td><td>'+f3+'</td><td>'+f4+'</td><td>'+f5+'</td><td>'+f6+'</td><td>'+f7+'</td><td>'+f8+'</td><td>'+f9+'</td><td>'+f10+'</td>';
        $('#produkty').find('tbody').append(row);
    });

    $('#usunWiersz').click(function() {
       $('#produkty').find('tbody tr:last').remove(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of pasting the php code, paste the script generated (copy from 'view source' in browser)

Comment: Please don't mix PHP and jQuery like this, it makes Jon Skeet cry.

Comment: it works when .change() function is separate from .click() functions

Comment: I don't think that mixing php and js is the problem here.

Comment: @Gary Green, you were right. For some reasons, the PHP code was the problem. I used the .clone() method instead and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tips to improve your code;

1. **Don't mix PHP and Javascript code.** Your asking for trouble and it just doesn't need to be done. If you need information from PHP available in your Javascript, then use `json_encode` -- don't write literally to the Javascript file like so:

   ```
   var userId = "<?php echo $_GET['user_id']; ?>"
   var postId = "<?php echo $_GET['post_id']; ?>"
   ```

   Instead have a PHP file that generates JSON object and have that loaded by a script tag:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/get_json.php"></script>
   ```

   Inside get_json.php will be this magic:

   ```
   <?php
      $json['user_id'] = $_GET['user_id'];
      $json['post_id'] = $_GET['post_id'];
      echo json_encode($json);
   ?>
   ```
2. **Don't repeat code.** All your `f1` `f2` are all unneeded. Why not just put this into a Javascript array, and `.join('</td><td>')` and add `<td>` and `</td>` onto the end.

   ```
   var inputsArray = ['<input name="email"/>','<input name="fullname"/>'];

   var tdString = '<td>' + inputsArray.join('</td><td>') + '</td>';
   ```

   Although I really don't see why you need PHP to help you create a form and HTML, especially as it's not even using any information specific within your PHP application. It's completely pointless.
3. **Use selectors appropriately and cache.**

   ```
   $('#'+par+' input[name="pkwiu[]"]').val(data.product_pkwiu);
   $('#'+par+' input[name="netto[]"]').val(data.product_netto);
   ```

   Doing this over doing `$('#'+par+'` over and over is inefficient. Use the context parameter to help you

   ```
   var $id = $('#' + par);
   $('input[name="pkwiu[]"]', $id).val(data.product_pkwiu);
   ```

   Notice the second parameter of `$` is used, which is telling jQuery to select inputs within that context (id of an element in this case). This allows us cache that id so jQuery isn't constantly trying to find it through each iteration.
4. **Don't tie yourself to your own HTML structure.**

   Avoid using parent parent parent parent parent parent, you get the idea. It'll cause headaches when you make even simple changes in your HTML structure

   ```
   var par = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id')`
   ```

   Instead it's far better to utilise the `.closest(selector)` (which travels up the DOM and stops when it reaches a match) `.parents(selector)` (which travels up the DOM and matches ALL elements for the selector up until the root, which is usually the body tag)

   Without seeing your HTML structure, it's hard to tell what `.parent().parent()` could be replaced with, but lets guess it's the form element:

   ```
   var par = $(this).closest('form').attr('id')`
   ```

Ok it's getting a little long now. There's plenty of other things I can pick apart, but for now, that's all folks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great stuff. It'll make me a better JS programmer. But what about a select list? It's generated dynamically and that's the main reason I used some PHP in my JS code. Should I generate the select list using JSON?

Comment: Well really the normal way to do this is to put it into a PHP file that generates HTML and outputs to the browser. If you want this loaded by Javascript, use ajax to get that HTML and put it in the DOM. Then you can attach events, manipulate the data/elements etc any way you like. Your currently writing HTML to a Javascript file *in PHP!*. This is such a weird flow.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```
<?php echo $head['site_link'];?>
```

I don't know what exactly you mean by "put them together". I suppose you mean, packing the functions into one .js-file. JS-Files however won't interpret PHP. So may be that is your mistake?

Comment: I meant, put them together in $(document).ready(function() {...})
sorry for my English

Comment: Ok. In which file, are you generating this output? A php or html-file?

Comment: Ok then this php-code will be executed properly and it's not the the issue in your problem. As I can see your problem is solved anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

For click and change events i would use binds.
http://api.jquery.com/bind/

```
// Click    
$('#dodajWiersz').bind('click', function() {
    $('#produkty').find('tbody tr:last').remove(); 
});


// Change
$('select[name="produkt[]"]').bind('change', function() {
   var id = $('select[name="produkt[]"] option:selected').val();
   var par = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
   $.getJSON(
       ...
```